# Is it possible to add defaults params for yadcf?

Tags: yadcf

Is there any way to set default params for filter style as below example?

```
 $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
        "ordering": false,
        "paging": false,
        "info": false,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "bla bla",

        },
    });
```

My yadcf exapmle is as below

```
yadcf.init($Table,
     [{
     column_number: 0,
     filter_default_label: "Filter By Category",
     filter_container_id: "FilterContainer_Category",
     reset_button_style_class: "yadcf-bg-dark-theme",
     style_class: "custom-select"
     }]
);
```

Comment: can you explain to what exactly do you mean by saying "default params for filter style" ?

Comment: @Daniel mean I would like to set once this params `reset_button_style_class: "yadcf-bg-dark-theme", style_class: "custom-select"` for my whole project may be in my common js file.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that you add as a third argument to the yadcf `init` function will be used as a global parameters,

So you can do the following

```
yadcf.init(oTable, [{
    column_number: 0
  },
  {
    column_number: 3
  }
], {
  reset_button_style_class: "yadcf-bg-dark-theme",
  style_class: "custom-select"
});
```

Comment: what does `oTable` mean that is global or must be defined for each table? Actually my question is simple I would like to use custom class for filter button or select

Comment: `oTable` is a table variable, you can set global per table not per yadcf

Comment: That is not common setting when I use that code in my common js file, it gives me error like this `ReferenceError: oTable is not defined` I would like to use this property as `$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, { ...`

Comment: oTable is not defined means that it was defined inside a function and not globally...

Comment: OK I think I can not set style once for all my project with pre-settings am I wrong? I must set style of filter control for every datatable separately?

Comment: thank you very much for your support and could you get plan this suggestion for next release?

Comment: you can add this as a new feature request but I'm not sure on when It will be added if at all because I don't have much spare time to add new features, but you can add a PR for it :)